# how can i pass a value to a function after event

Tags: jquery, oop, jquery-plugins

```
            uiSlider: function(){                                   
                var arrLength = (this.cDat).length - 1,                 
                    value = this.cDat,                      
                    pieTitle = this.cDet,
                    config = this.anyChartConfig(); 

                    console.log( this.anyChartConfig(2) );              

                $( "#slider" ).slider({
                  range: "min",
                  min: 0,
                  max: arrLength,
                  step: 1,
                  change: function ( event, ui ) {                              
                    console.log( this.anyChartConfig(ui.value) );
                  }
                })
                .each(function() {
                  var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;                      
                  var vals = opt.max - opt.min;                   
                  for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {                     
                    var el = $('<label>'+ ( value[i]["title"] ) +'</label>').css('left',(i/vals*100)+'%');                      
                    $( "#slider" ).append(el);
                  }
                });                                             
            },
```

In the first console.log() it display properly, but it the second console.log() it give me an error of {Object doesn't support property or method 'anyChartConfig'}. And also I want to get the value and pass it to the function after the change,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside the slider callback(`change`) is a different object(it is the `#slider` element) than what was `this` in the `uiSlider` method.

A possible solution is to use a closure variable `self` as shown below

```
uiSlider: function(){                                   
    var arrLength = (this.cDat).length - 1,                 
        value = this.cDat,                      
        pieTitle = this.cDet,
        config = this.anyChartConfig(), self = this; 

    console.log( this.anyChartConfig(2) );              

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: arrLength,
        step: 1,
        change: function ( event, ui ) {                              
            console.log( self.anyChartConfig(ui.value) );
        }
    })
    .each(function() {
        var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;                      
        var vals = opt.max - opt.min;                   
        for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {                     
            var el = $('<label>'+ ( value[i]["title"] ) +'</label>').css('left',(i/vals*100)+'%');                      
            $( "#slider" ).append(el);
        }
    });                                             
}
```

Why? Probably you can understand more about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [closure variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: its finally working! :) Can you explain it to me why to I need to declare a variable self = this?